# How to get new array between selected two dates using javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

My javascript array like that. `var datearray = ["2010-01-10","2010-01-20","2014-01-35","2014-10-22","2014-03-02","2010-02-11","2010-03-18","2010-09-09","2014-11-12","2014-02-23","2014-03-02","2014-03-02","2014-04-22","2014-05-09","2014-02-23","","2010-02-19","2010-03-01","2010-02-27","2010-02-25"];`

but my searching dates are `startDate = 2010-01-01;` and `endDate = 2010-03-29;` I want to get new date array between above startDate and endDate; How I created It.

Comment: at least show some effort and post your code

Comment: I don't know the context for this question, but if you plan on doing more than just this operation on the array, you should map the array to `Date` objects (or ints representing time since Jan 1, 1970) and sort it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var dateArray = ["2010-01-10","2010-01-20","2014-01-35","2014-10-22","2014-03-02","2010-02-11","2010-03-18","2010-09-09","2014-11-12","2014-02-23","2014-03-02","2014-03-02","2014-04-22","2014-05-09","2014-02-23","","2010-02-19","2010-03-01","2010-02-27","2010-02-25"],
    startDate = Date.parse("2010-01-01"),
    endDate = Date.parse("2010-03-29");

var filteredDateArray = dateArray.filter(function(s) {
  s = Date.parse(s);
  return s > startDate && s < endDate;
});

console.log(filteredDateArray);
```